# Replacing middle of a dynamic string

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I know this can be done using preg_replace but I have no idea how to set it up and the only examples I can find online all use a pre defined string (ie - $text = 'this is my text';).

I need to replace certain parts of the string which is being called dynamically from the database with the letter 'X'.

For example.

```
  $from = $row["From"];
```

Right now, echoing $from will show something like :

```
 011234567889
```

I want it to output something like :

```
 01123XXXX889
```

I'm really stumped here so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: So which `certain parts` do you need to replace? If you can't give us a definition for `certain parts` it makes it very difficult for us to give you a meaningful answer

Comment: `$start = substr($from, 0, 4); $end = substr($from, -3); echo $start.'XXXX'.$end;`

Comment: `$from = substr($from, 0, 5) . 'XXXX' . substr($from, 9)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that. I'd like to replace say the 4 characters from the 4th character in. so 123456789 would become 123XXX789

Comment: Wow that simple? Bloody hell! Thanks Mark that works perfectly ;)

Comment: `preg_replace('/(.{4})(.{4})(.*)/', '\1XXXX\3', $from);`

Comment: @Grant: Mark's suggestion is what I'd use, but if you want to use `preg_replace`, you could do something like `$str = preg_replace('/^(.{4}).{4}/', '$1XXXX', $str);` to replace the first 8 characters with the first 4 + 4 X's

Comment: @mudasobwa: back-references in PHP are `$<N>`, not `\<N>`. Besides, you needn't match the 4 chars you are replacing, nor should you bother matching the trailing chars (cf my previous comment)